# Error 0x80070643 - Can't get the update

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, windows-update, sql-server

I'm trying to get the update which is `Security Update for SQL Server 2016 SP2 (KB4293802)` from Windows Update on my Windows 10. However it returns me `Security Update for SQL Server 2016 SP2 (KB4293802) -Error 0x80070643` error.

Therefore I downloaded the update from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=57264) to manual installing but I'm getting failure now. The following log file, which is shown after uncompleted setup, contains information as follows:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  The patch installer has failed to update the following instance: MSSQLSERVER. To determine the reason for failure, review the log files.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068709375
  Start time:                    2019-06-05 01:27:52
  End time:                      2019-06-05 01:30:46
  Requested action:              Patch

Instance MSSQLSERVER overall summary:
  Final result:                  The patch installer has failed to update the shared features. To determine the reason for failure, review the log files.
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068709375
  Exit facility code:            1202
  Exit error code:               1
  Exit message:                  The NT service 'SQLPBDMS' could not be stopped.
  Start time:                    2019-06-05 01:28:36
  End time:                      2019-06-05 01:30:44
  Requested action:              Patch
  Exception help link:           http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=13.0.5081.1&EvtType=0xAC454CB1%400xF762992B%401202%401&EvtType=0xAC454CB1%400xF762992B%401202%401

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  ****
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Microsoft Windows 10 ****
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     ****
  OS language:                   English (****)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5026.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            SQL Server Replication                   1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5026.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search 1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5026.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            PolyBase Query Service for External Data 1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5026.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            R Services (In-Database)                 1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5026.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER            sql_inst_mr                              1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5026.0     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016      MSSQLSERVER          MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER             Reporting Services - Native              1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5081.1     No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          SSMS                                     1033                                      13.0.16106.4    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          Client Tools Connectivity                1033                                      13.0.14500.10   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          Client Tools Backwards Compatibility     1033                                      13.0.14500.10   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          Client Tools SDK                         1033                                      13.0.14500.10   No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2016                                                          LocalDB                                  1033                 Express Edition      13.2.5081.1     No         Yes      

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2016 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2016
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       13
  SPLevel:                       2
  KBArticle:                     KB4293802
  KBArticleHyperlink:            http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=4293802
  PatchType:                     GDR
  AssociatedHotfixBuild:         5158
  Platform:                      x64
  PatchLevel:                    13.2.5081.1
  ProductVersion:                13.2.5026.0
  GDRReservedRange:              13.0.1700.0:13.0.1899.0;13.0.4200.0:13.0.4299.0;13.0.5200.0:13.0.5399.0
  Installation location:         C:\cd2734868aa85d93cc33ba11c023\x64\setup\ 

Updated product edition:
  Instance             Edition             
  MSSQLSERVER          Express             

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Patch
  ALLINSTANCES:                  false
  CLUSTERPASSIVE:                false
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             
  ENU:                           false
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS:      true
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCEID:                    <empty>
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  MRCACHEDIRECTORY:              
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  SUPPRESSPRIVACYSTATEMENTNOTICE: false
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20190605_012732\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

I found similar questions about this but couldn't reach a conclusion with them. How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT 1:** 
[Result of `sc query SQLPBDMS` and `sc.exe stop SQLPBDMS`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxDoL.jpg)

**EDIT 2:** 
[Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6XPk.jpg)

Comment: Given: "The NT service 'SQLPBDMS' could not be stopped." I assume this service exists and it's current state is running?  Can you run: `sc query SQLPBDMS` to check, then maybe try `sc.exe stop SQLPBDMS` What message do you get?

Comment: @HelpingHand I added the outputs returned from commands in the first edit. If you mean 'SQL Server PolyBase Data Movement' with 'SQLPBDMS' I found it in the Services and its status is 'Starting' and 'Start' and 'Stop' buttons disabled for it. I don't know whether it is correct but I tried to start 'SQL Server PolyBase Engine' to enable 'Start' and 'Stop' buttons for 'SQL Server PolyBase Data Movement' from Services but get a warning as in the edit two.

Comment: Is the process that is this service running?  If you look in services.msc for this service and find the path to the binary, is this process running?  Can you terminate it?  I think if you could stop this service then you'd be OK.

Comment: @HelpingHand The problem solved by starting update after disabling 'SQL Server PolyBase Data Movement' and 'SQL Server PolyBase Engine'. If you write your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most significant error in the log is:

> The NT service 'SQLPBDMS' could not be stopped.

The steps to understand the state and corrext it would be:

1. Confirm the state of the service by running the command:

   > sc.exe queryex SQLPBDMS

   I assume the state is something like "Start Pending".
2. Locate the process repsonsible for the service.  The ImagePath value under:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SQLPBDMS
   should help.  Otherwise check in Services.msc
   You could try and kill the process if it is running.
3. Reboot the computer, does it start and therefore in a better state to be stopped?
4. Change the service startup type to manaual or disabled in Services.msc, and then reboot the computer.

Once the service is stopped then attempt to re-apply the update.